# Internal RD1000 devices are Dell proprietary?

Tags: usb, drivers, sata

I recently purchased two Dell RD1000 devices, one internal and one external. The external RD1000 connects via USB to the computer without problems, however the internal RD1000 via SATA is not recognized by the computer. I've searched (maybe not enough), and I haven't found any writing where it explicitly says that internal RD1000 devices can only be connected to Dell computers. My motherboard is a Gigabyte B250-DSH3 and the Windows version is Windows 10 v22H2 (OS comp. 19045.2251).
Maybe there is a specific driver that I couldn't find.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard SATA drive but there are 2 things to keep in mind:

1 Your Bios may not recognize the drive, if there is no cartridge in it.
2 And your Bios must support hot-plugging SATA devices (not all do).

If you have a SATA port that supports E-SATA changes are a lot better that it will work on that particular port (as E-SATA must support hot-plugging).

Comment: The BIOS does detect the device, in fact it even puts it in the boot device list. I activated the hot-plugging SATA devices option. The problem is in the Windows interface. In the device manager I do not see changes when I insert the cartridge or remove it, neither in the disk management. The cartridge is fine as I can access it through the external RD1000.

Comment: @DarilAlemán Does Windows Device manager recognize the drive at all? If not: The drivers come with the Dell Powervault RD1000 utility. There is no W10 version, but the drivers from teh Server 2019 version should work.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I installed two or three versions of the dell utility and it didn't work. Where only the rd1000 is seen is in the setup. It seems that it is not possible to use it on Windows 10 :(